# How to get SharedPreference Value from Activity to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am currently saving value in SharedPreference in Main Activity:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences(
            APP_CONSTANT, MODE_PRIVATE);
final String someKey = "com.APP.NAME.myApp";        
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();         
prefs.edit().putString(someKey , date.toString());            
prefs.edit().apply();
```

Now when i initiate BroadcastReceiver's onRecieve function and try to get the value of someKey  from SharedPreferences, it is always coming as null.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences(
          APP_CONSTANT, MODE_PRIVATE);
final String someKey = "com.APP.NAME.myApp";       
final String someKeyValue = prefs.getString(someKey, null);
```

The someKeyValue is always coming as null. Please advise how can I access it in BroadcastReceiver from Activity.

I also tried using getApplicationContext in BroadcastReceiver but it is not working in BroadcastReceiver. I understand that both the Activity and BroadcastReceiver are having different contexts so how can I share the sharedpreference values in both of them. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean a BroadcastReceiver? If yes, this should work. The broadcast receiver should be a part of the same application which generates the broadcast in this case, to have access to the same SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yes BroadcastReciever...but I am getting null value.

Comment: I am assuming the BroadcastReceiver is within the same application. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, but i just noticed, the values are not getting saved in MainActivity at all. The line  prefs.getString(someKey ,null)); is always returning null, why is that? I am saving lik this prefs.edit().putString(someKey , date.toString());            
prefs.edit().apply();

Comment: It is just returning default value.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to use .apply() after end of line

```
       prefs.edit().putString(someKey , date.toString()).apply();
```

After doing this the values are not null anymore.